# sequence operators not supported for type 'system.string'

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

what is the problem in this query

```
              var ptypes = (from mf in _pagecontext.PagesRefs
                let a = mf.nvcr_Slug.Substring(mf.nvcr_Slug.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)  // gets everything after /
                let b = Regex.Replace(a, @"[\d-]+$", m => m.Value.Replace('-', '='))   // replace last char with =
                let cc = (b.Contains('=') ? b.Substring(0, b.IndexOf("=")) : b) // strip off everything before = to get original string
                let cm = stroriginal  // string to search
                where cm.Equals(cc)
                select mf);
```

nvcr_slug could be

```
mazhar-kaunain-baig-3-4
mazhar-kaunain-baig-3-4/mazhar-kaunain-baig-3-4
mazhar-kaunain-baig-3-4/mazhar-kaunain-baig-3-4/mazhar-kaunain-baig
abc
abc/abc
abc/abc/abc
```

Comment: I'll ask you the same "what is the problem in this query"?

Comment: it is giving sequence operators not supported for type 'system.string' error

Comment: at what stage does the error occur ? i.e. which line is it

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

Based on your comment - I think this should work:

`let b = Regex.Replace(a, @".$", '=')`

In each iteration over the collection with LINQ you are dealing with just one value - the above should capture the last character in the given string and replace it with `=`

---

The first thing that I can think of is a conflict between LINQ and System.String implementations of the method `Contains` on:

`b.Contains('=')`

Try using System.String.Contains explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
let cc = (b.Contains("=") ? b.Substring(0, b.IndexOf("=")) : b)
```

and try.